# convert txt tables to python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I have multiple text files which contain some tables , most of the tables are of these two types. I want a way to convert these tables into python dictionaries.

```
                         precision    recall  f1-score   support

       BASE_RENT_ANNUAL       0.53      0.57      0.55      1408
      BASE_RENT_MONTHLY       0.65      0.54      0.59      3904
          BASE_RENT_PSF       0.68      0.59      0.63      1248
 RENT_INCREMENT_MONTHLY       0.63      0.44      0.52      7530
SECURITY_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT       0.88      0.89      0.88      3557

              micro avg       0.69      0.58      0.63     17647
              macro avg       0.67      0.61      0.63     17647
           weighted avg       0.68      0.58      0.62     17647



Hard Evaluation Metrics
--------------------------------------------------

Reading predictions from /mnt/c/Users/Aleksandra/mlbuddy/python/bilstm/training/test_predictions.txt...
Nb tokens in test set: 957800

Reading training data from /mnt/c/Users/Aleksandra/mlbuddy/python/bilstm/corpus/train.txt...
Nb tokens in training set: 211153

Strict mode: OFF

---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Test tokens   Nb tokens   Nb words   Nb errors   Token error rate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
            all      957800       5408       39333             0.0411
---------------------------------------------------------------------
       unseen-I         704         19         704             1.0000
       unseen-O       59870       1724       10208             0.1705
     unseen-all       60574       1743       10912             0.1801
---------------------------------------------------------------------
         diff-I       13952         70       13952             1.0000
         diff-O        5285        121        4645             0.8789
     diff-etype           0          0           0             0.0000
       diff-all       19237        191       18597             0.9667
---------------------------------------------------------------------
all-unseen+diff       79811       1934       29509             0.3697
---------------------------------------------------------------------


Avg TER on unseen and diff: 0.5734
```

I have tried this in my code to convert the second table to dictionary but it is not working as expected.:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

    with open("idm.txt") as f:
        dp = dropwhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("-"), f)
        next(dp)  # skip ----
        names = next(dp).split()  # get headers names
        next(f)  # skip -----
        out = []
        for line in takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith("-"), f):
            a, b = line.rsplit(None, 1)
            out.append(dict(zip(names, a.split(None, 7) + [b])))
```

Expected output:

```
{BASE_RENT_ANNUAL: {precision:0.53,recall:0.57,f1-score:0.55,support:1408},
BASE_RENT_MONTHLY: {...}, ..
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output of 2nd table?

Answer (score 0):

Not the same approach, but the following could be a beginning to your true solution

```
txt = '''                        precision    recall  f1-score   support

       BASE_RENT_ANNUAL       0.53      0.57      0.55      1408
      BASE_RENT_MONTHLY       0.65      0.54      0.59      3904
          BASE_RENT_PSF       0.68      0.59      0.63      1248
 RENT_INCREMENT_MONTHLY       0.63      0.44      0.52      7530
SECURITY_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT       0.88      0.89      0.88      3557

              micro avg       0.69      0.58      0.63     17647
              macro avg       0.67      0.61      0.63     17647
           weighted avg       0.68      0.58      0.62     17647



Hard Evaluation Metrics
--------------------------------------------------

Reading predictions from /mnt/c/Users/Aleksandra/mlbuddy/python/bilstm/training/test_predictions.txt...
Nb tokens in test set: 957800

Reading training data from /mnt/c/Users/Aleksandra/mlbuddy/python/bilstm/corpus/train.txt...
Nb tokens in training set: 211153

Strict mode: OFF

---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Test tokens   Nb tokens   Nb words   Nb errors   Token error rate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
            all      957800       5408       39333             0.0411
---------------------------------------------------------------------
       unseen-I         704         19         704             1.0000
       unseen-O       59870       1724       10208             0.1705
     unseen-all       60574       1743       10912             0.1801
---------------------------------------------------------------------
         diff-I       13952         70       13952             1.0000
         diff-O        5285        121        4645             0.8789
     diff-etype           0          0           0             0.0000
       diff-all       19237        191       18597             0.9667
---------------------------------------------------------------------
all-unseen+diff       79811       1934       29509             0.3697
---------------------------------------------------------------------


Avg TER on unseen and diff: 0.5734'''

lst1 = [x.split() for x in txt.split('\n') if x]
lst2 = [(x[0],x[1:]) for x in lst1 if (not x[0].startswith('-') and x[0] == x[0].upper())]
dico = dict(lst2)
dico2 = {}
for k in dico:
    dico2[k] = {'precision':dico[k][0],'recall':dico[k][1],'f1-score':dico[k][2],'support':dico[k][3]}
print(dico2)
```